# Problems with closing and starting a Python program quickly

Tags: python, pyqt, restart

I have a small python/pyqt-program which functions fine the first time I run it. But if I close it and restart it quickly (in about 3 secs) this definition will give the wrong result. It runs fine without error but the **if oktype** will not return true even if its the exactly same file as first time I ran it! Has it anything to do with this code? Or is it higher up in my code, or maybe some sort of garbage-collection errors?

```
def fileChanged(fileIn, pubNotes, fileType):
    pubNotes.clear()
    fileType.clear()

    filename = str(fileIn.text())

    foundtype = 0
    oktype = ''
    okfiles = ('.max','.ma','.mb','.ni','.nk', '.psd','.ztl', '.tif', '.tiff')
    for ftype in okfiles:
        if filename.endswith(ftype):
            print('File: %s matches pattern %s') % (filename,ftype)
            foundtype = 1
            print 'ftype er %s' % ftype
            oktype = ftype
            break

    if foundtype:
        print('File is of type %s') % oktype
        if oktype is '.psd':
            typeopt = ['Matte Paint','Texture paint']
            for i in range(len(typeopt)):
                fileType.addItem(typeopt)
        if oktype is '.nk':
            typeopt = ['Comp', 'Precomp', 'Roto']
            for i in range(len(typeopt)):
                fileType.addItem(typeopt[i])
        if oktype is '.max':
            typeopt = ['Model']
            for i in range(len(typeopt)):
                fileType.addItem(typeopt[i])
        if oktype is '.tif':
            typeopt = ['Texture']
            for i in range(len(typeopt)):
                fileType.addItem(typeopt[i])
            #update comboBox_types here
    else:
        messageBox('File is not of known type, please drag other file')
        fileIn.clear
```

Comment: Have you tried using `oktype ==` instead of `oktype is`?

Comment: Nothing to do with garbage collection- the problem is almost certainly the actual file handle, if it didn't close correctly or otherwise needs to be cleaned up by the operating system.

Comment: TyrantWave: there is no difference for string comparison.

Comment: @DavidRobinson, you are wrong, `is` compares references. Try in shell: `foo = 'foo'; foo += 'bar';foo is 'foobar';foo == 'foobar'` first will `False`, second `True`

Comment: `okfiles[5] == '.psd'; okfiles[5] is '.psd'`.  First prints `True`, second prints `False`.

Comment: You are quite right- I was thinking, foolishly, only of individual string literals. On the other hand, I think that does apply to this situation. I can't reproduce what Zachary Young is saying; when I print those two booleans, both print `True`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes! @TyrantWave and @reclosedev you are absolutely correct. I switched to using == instead of is and now it works like a charm! Thank you so much!